# UITextView resign first responder on 'Done'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have been searching around the web for about an hour now, and cannot find any code to help me with this.

I have a `UITextView` that I need to resign first responder of when the user presses the 'Done' button on their keyboard.

I have seen code floating around the internet like this:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
 [textField resignFirstResponder];
 return NO;
}
```

But that will not work for a `UITextView`.
Simply put,
How can I tell when the user presses the done button on the keyboard?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Implement the   `shouldChangeTextInRange:` delegate method.

Use below approach and the solution work only with @"\n" (new line character).

```
//In you *.h file make sure you add
@interface v1ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    myTextField.delegate = self;
}

    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
          replacementText:(NSString *)text
        {

            if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

                [textView resignFirstResponder];
                // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
                return NO;
            }
            // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
            return YES;
    }
```

Comment: I have that set up. how can I detect when that is pressed.

Comment: set textfield  delegate like  `myTextField.delegate = self;` and return `YES` in `textFieldShouldReturn` method;

Comment: @Jhaliya please Read the OP, it is a text VIEW not a text FIELD

Comment: @Jhaliya I see you updated your post, Isn't it better to use 'YES' and 'NO' instead of 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' in obj-c?

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III : Updated answer.

Answer (score -4):

You can use the delegate method

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView { 
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

You have to set your controller as the delegate for the TextView.
For more methods you can have a look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006897

Comment: Did not work, Nothing different happened in my application. I have my delegate set up, and I have the keyboard setup the way I want it, but That code never gets called.

Comment: `textViewDidEndEditing:` is called when edition finished, in other words when the textView already resigned the first responder so `[textView resignFirstResponder];` inside of it won't have any effect.