# resigning the keyboard for textview

Tags: ios, uitextview

Hi i am using ten textfields and two textviews in my code. I am resigning the keyboard for textfields when next button is tapped. But i don't know how to resign the textview. Is there any delegate like textfield should return for textview. If any please post it here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **[textView resignFirstResponder];** Tried.?

Comment: There is nothing much difference from UITextVfield . check with their delegates ., Then you will come to know ...

Comment: @KumarKl i know this piece of line. But my doubt is for textfield we can implement it in textfieldshouldreturn. Similarly is there any delegate in textview?

Comment: (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
          replacementText:(NSString *)text

Comment: CHeck out **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411858/uitextview-resign-first-responder-on-done**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with diffrent way

**Edit**:

1) Put .h File  "UITextViewDelegate"

If from .xib then set it textView as delegate

[image]

Write this delegate method

```
  #pragma mark - UITextView Delegate
  - (BOOL) textView: (UITextView*) textView shouldChangeTextInRange: (NSRange) range
      replacementText: (NSString*) String
     {
         if ([String isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
             return NO;
          }
        return YES;
      }
```

2) textView resign when you touch on view.

Put .h File  "UIGestureRecognizerDelegate"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {

     UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
     recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
     recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
     [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
      recognizer.delegate = self;
  }

   - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
      {
          [Your_textView resignFirstResponder];//Take as global Your_textView
           return NO;
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

There’s no shouldReturn on UITextView, but you can implement UITextViewDelegate and watch for insertions:

```
- (BOOL) textView: (UITextView*) textView shouldChangeTextInRange: (NSRange) range
replacementText: (NSString*) text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
         [textView resignFirstResponder];
         return NO;
    }
     return YES;
}
```